# script keeps triggering when using `bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()`

Tags: python

From the code down below, then I remove `bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()`, everything runs fine. But with that line, it prints so much stuff so fast that I can't read it and have to close blender.

```py
import bpy

ctx = bpy.context


def object_selected(context):
    ctx = bpy.context
    selected = ctx.object
    if selected and selected.name == "Next":
        print(">")
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()

        
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(object_selected)
```

What I don't get is that I hit the play button manually, everything goes fine and the print only appears once.

Why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the handler: `depsgraph_update_post`, your function will run when some blender data changes.

In case 1: without `animation_play()`
You update blender data manually and trigger the function, so it prints once.

In case 2: with `animation_play()`
Run `animation_play()` will update the blender data, so it trigger the handler function again, get an infinite loop.

To fix this, use a global variable to make the function non-repeatable.

```
import bpy

ctx = bpy.context

is_running = False

def object_selected(context):
    global is_running
    if is_running: return
    is_running = True

    ctx = bpy.context
    selected = ctx.object
    if selected and selected.name == "Next":
        print(">")
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()

    is_running = False

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(object_selected)
```